# iOS 4 retina display resolution size

Tags: dpi, resolution, ppi

I'm a little confused about the resolution here, I know the dimensions suppose to be: 320x480 points but what do I need to put for the resolution? e.g. 300 dpi?

I'm designing on CS5.

Comment: Flash CS5 or Photoshop CS5? (I have no idea about Flash iOS dev and the Retina display so I don't know if resolution is involved.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming. The iPhone 4 display is 640×960 at 326 ppi, as documented in many places.

Comment: What you set the PPI/DPI for exported images doesn't matter. iOS ignores this. What matters is that you have the dimensions right (for non-Retina displays), and you exactly double the dimensions for Retina display (iPhone 4). See my answer below.

Comment: also, the term `points` in this context refers to a unit of css measurement specific to the iPhone. You shouldn't be setting anything up in points within PhotoShop...just pixels.

Answer (score 7):

> **Should my images be saved at a specific PPI?**
>
> No. iOS ignores PPI (pixels per inch) stored inside images. However,
>   the pixel dimensions of your images do matter, so make sure you get
>   those right. It’s also important to ensure your 2× images are exactly
>   double the dimensions of your 1× images and that elements within the
>   image are in the same positions—your Retina images should be identical
>   content to their smaller counterparts, but with more detail.

(via http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina2/)

Read the above article it's invaluable, if you're designing for iOS. Dimensions matter, the PPI is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

iPhone4 retina displays are 960x640 with 326 dpi (ppi).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_display#Display

Comment: Found what I was looking for, 326 dpi

Comment: uh, no yashar...that's the pixel density of the screen. Not any sort of DPI setting for the images you create. In fact, it doesn't matter what DPI setting you use, as it's irrelevant on the screen.