# Screenshots from different computers/monitors have different dpi

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution, dpi, screenshot

Has anyone had this issue where they get screenshots from different sources, say two different computers/monitors - pull those screenshots into photoshop, only to find they are different in DPI and/or size.

Even if we are using the same screencap tool, capturing the same size, same browser and everything.

I suspected it was to do with retina screens/monitors compared to older monitors. But this was just a hunch. Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 2):

Well it depends on the resolution of the monitor you're doing a screen capture of.

Say I do a full screenshot of a 1920x1080 monitor. My final image will be 1920x1080 pixels.

If I do a full screenshot of my 27" mac that is 2560 x 1440, then my image will be 2560 x 1440 pixels.

Note that even though 2 monitors may be the same physical size, 1 monitor could have a higher resolution and is upscaling the system but the screenshot would capture the actual resolution set by the user.

Comment: And then you have the multi-monitor setups

Answer (score -2):

I think your question is kinda duplicate!
[What is the difference between DPI (dots per inch) and PPI (pixels per inch)?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6080/what-is-the-difference-between-dpi-dots-per-inch-and-ppi-pixels-per-inch?rq=1)

DPI or Dots per inch is defined and used for CRT displays. In fact monitors don't have dots, They have pixels.
BTW, DPI is used for Image printing, both DPI and resolution are interchangeably also used but actually they are different definitions!

> In printing, DPI (dots per inch) refers to the output resolution of a printer or imagesetter, and PPI (pixels per inch) refers to the input resolution of a photograph or image. DPI refers to the physical dot density of an image when it is reproduced as a real physical entity, for example printed onto paper. A digitally stored image has no inherent physical dimensions, measured in inches or centimeters. Some digital file formats record a DPI value, or more commonly a PPI (pixels per inch) value, which is to be used when printing the image. This number lets the printer or software know the intended size of the image, or in the case of scanned images, the size of the original scanned object. For example, a bitmap image may measure 1,000 × 1,000 pixels, a resolution of 1 megapixel. If it is labeled as 250 PPI, that is an instruction to the printer to print it at a size of 4 × 4 inches. Changing the PPI to 100 in an image editing program would tell the printer to print it at a size of 10×10 inches. However, changing the PPI value would not change the size of the image in pixels which would still be 1,000 × 1,000. An image may also be resampled to change the number of pixels and therefore the size or resolution of the image, but this is quite different from simply setting a new PPI for the file.