# What is difference between overprint, pass, resolution, PPI and DPI in design printing?

Tags: print-design, resolution, dpi, ppi

I have read through many resources but I still don't understand what are the difference between them. Can anyone give good examples that is able for me to imagine the different and explain what is difference between them?

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between DPI (dots per inch) and PPI (pixels per inch)?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6080/what-is-the-difference-between-dpi-dots-per-inch-and-ppi-pixels-per-inch) You ask multiple questions and most of them already have an answer on GD.

Comment: Overprint is put ink of element on top of element under in print. Pass is a term used in FX industry for caching the output of a render so it can be later composited on top of the other for efficiency/flexibility/compatibility reasons. Resolution is not defined without context, it could deal with vastly different things. PPI is metadata in the file requesting how to scale the file for print (alternatively a measure of a screen resolution, guide for buying screen not meaningful for designers again context), DPI is the same as PPI sort of but for mediums that dont have continuous color.

Comment: (DPI can also be the measure of a printers output resolution, again context. Rather useless metric though better know the LPI or the LPI equivalent of a stochastic rasters). All in all these terms dont matter much. But that said i wouldn't hire a graphic designer that does not know what PPI and DPI is to print jobs for me (too inexperienced and too risky might be wasting my money)